# Скролл замирает на форме ( iPhone)

Tags: php, html, css

Здравствуйте, есть [сайт](http://day-camp.study.ua/) , в нём есть форма, если через айфон открыть сайт и проскролить до формы, то скролл замирает и больше не двигается с этой формы, с чем может быть связанна проблема.
При нажатии на любое поле формы, сайт проскраливаеться вниз ( с телефона)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема возникает из-за вашего плагина для анимации скролла. Я бы посоветовал вовсе отказаться от него, или же хотя применять только в Windows - на macOS и мобильный ОС такие плагины только ухудшают юзабилити.

Также я бы посоветовал в целом протестировать веб-сайт и исправить на нём множество багов.

К примеру, в Safari у вас JS валится: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$("#video-bg")[0].play')`

А ещё у вас текст наезжает на блок, если менять высоту окна:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Возьмусь предположить, что это происходит из-за того, что ваша форма находится внутри `iframe` и из-за этого не обрабатывается событие `scroll`, что висит на всём документе. Рекомендую вам отказаться от использования `iframe` либо использовать другой плагин для стилизации скролл бара, либо вообще отказаться от стилизации скролл бара. Например: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ . С ним подобных проблем не наблюдалось.